# Docker-compose and .dockerignore

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There is small config of docker-compose with Dockerfiles and .dockerignore files I have in subdirectories. I can't understand why my images after build include everything even I have some items to ignore in .dockerignore. Here is what I have

```
docker-compose.yml
docker
├── app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── .dockerignore
└── web
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── nginx.conf
    └── .dockerignore
```

Example of .dockerignore:

```
**/.dockerignore
docker-compose.yml
log
**/log
../../log
```

I just run this as follows:

```
docker-compose up -d --build --no-cache
```

None of the above ignored.. What am I doing wrong?

```
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

Adding Dockerfile for the app service (see docker-compose). Docker-compose packs two images with ROR app and nginx. For both dockerfiles I have dockerignore. So my understanding is that I can say what exactly I want in each. But it is not. How can I ignore some of the files in package? Or should I put my Dockerfile and dockerignore in different paths since build works only inside the context.. I am confused.

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs imagemagick
# Configuring main directory
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/example.com
WORKDIR /var/www/example.com
# Setting env up
ENV RAILS_ENV='production'
ENV RACK_ENV='production'

# Adding gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5 --without development test
# Adding project files
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

So I thought that `COPY . .`  checks .dockerignore first.. no?

Comment: Try `*` instead of `**`. I think `**` doesn't work in `.dockerignore`. Also, what exactly do your images include that you want to be excluded?

Comment: The actual contents of the `docker-compose.yml` file seems essential to debug this; seeing the two `Dockerfile`s wouldn't hurt either.  If you're using Docker bind mounts (`volumes:`) to replace everything in the image with your local source tree, that doesn't look at the `.dockerignore` files.

Comment: The build should ignore these files, so you'll need to provide a [mcve] to get help on this. Your examples are incomplete and haven't been reduced to the minimum needed to allow someone else to try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `docker-compose` seems to have had a long history of handling `.dockerignore` wrong or not at all for ages, apparently; see e.g. [#1607](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1607), [#3886](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3886). If you have any trouble, definitely update to the latest version ... and pray. :/

Comment: Are you using volumes? If you use volumes, then .dockerignore will ignore the files being mirrored by those volumes.

Comment: Let me tell you a funny fact.




i was searching about 4 hours and i found out my `dockerignore` file  was getting ignored by docker cause of a miss spell and writing capital `I`.




`dockerignore` VS `dockerIgnore`!!!




god i'm going to cry 

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have 2 `Dockerfiles`, which have their separate contexts. In each context (folder) you have `.dockerignore`, and that is correct. But `.dockerignore` **does not** work outside of build context, that means using `../../` is wrong.

I guess you are supposing these files to apply to `docker` folder, but in fact they apply to `docker/app` and `docker/web` respectively.

The build process is following:

First `docker cli` packs the context (folder with `Dockerfile` if not specified explicitly) and sends it to `docker daemon`. Nothing **outside** this folder is sent. It is written explicitly for `COPY` command, which is used to put the context items into container:

> The `src` path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot
>   COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build
>   is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
>   daemon.

If there is `.dockerignore`, the ignored files **are excluded** before packing.

Comment: Thanks for heads up. Can you check dockerfile above. Still not clear.

Comment: *You have 2 Dockerfiles, which have their separate contexts. In each context (folder) you have .dockerignore, and that is correct.*
one .dockerignore for each Dockerfile didnt work for me, none of files werw ignored in build, just after I united them to one and placed to docker-compose.yml it worked

Answer (score 21):

I struggled with this until I came across [this article](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/bigger-dockerignore-smaller-docker-images-49fa22e51c7) which helped me understand what was happening in my case. If you are binding everything to the container e.g `.:/app` or `.:/usr/src/app` as it is common during development for hot reloading, we are completely ignoring `.dockerignore` since the bind mounts are attached after the image is built, even files that were ignored are now mounted to the container. I removed the binding and files specified in `.dockerignore` were ignored.

I still bind everything during development but when building production images, I do not

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. The problem was so obvious yet hard to find.

Comment: Encountered the same problem, I probably spent 3 hours debugging. I finally SSH-d into the Docker container to finally realise that `node_modules` was not there, even though it should have been. Thanks for your comment though, after hours of googling this is the first one that finally explained my problem.

Answer (score 14):

The `.dockerignore` needs to be in the root directory/context folder as you specified in the `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me is to put the `.dockerignore` at the root of my app, where the `docker-compose.yml` is.